# Storyboard Animation of multiple listbox's item background in code behind

Tags: wpf, animation, canvas, storyboard

I am stuck in a problem... hope someone can help.
I have a canvas with multiple view objects. These view objects has ListBox component. I am trying to perform animation in a fashion as ,

```
{CanvasItem[1],ListBoxItem[2],BackgroundColor=Red} .. similarly    
{CanvasItem[3],ListBoxItem[1],BackgroundColor=Yellow}... and so on.
```

How to do this... using Storyboard (...using keyframes) in code behind.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Joe. I think that you'll have more luck receiving answers if you read the [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) page of the Stack Overflow Help Center and then come back to edit your question according to the advice given in that page.

Comment: could you show some code, cs or xaml whatever you have. appreciated if you could put more details in the question.